# Android : How to Load PDF?

Tags: android, pdf

Is there any way to load PDF file from Asset/URL in Browser or WebView or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to do this at the moment. However, you could write your own pdf viewer activity. Also, check out [RepliGo Reader](http://www.cerience.com/products/android/reader/index.htm) and [PDF GView](http://uk.androlib.com/android.application.zeg-android-pdfgview-ztjD.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Instead loading PDF file from local resource, you can think about open it online using Google Docs Viewer:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```