# How to load a pdf on android from a url?

Tags: android, url, pdf, android-listview

I have a page that contains a listView and each item is supposed to open a pdf file from a url, but I don't know how to load a pdf file from a url or even how to load a pdf, so I was asking if anyone can tell me any tips on how to do that? Thanks

Comment: This is duplicate. check below links<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079923/open-pdf-in-android-app
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480974/how-to-open-pdf-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WebView webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String filename = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
String filename1 = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters1.pdf";
```

possible duplicate :
[Android : How to Load PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761107/android-how-to-load-pdf)

pass separate seperate URl on

```
  ListView lt = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            lt.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (arg2 == 1) {
                          webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);
                    }

                    if (arg2 == 2) {
    webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename1);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: I don't understand the last 2 lines can you explain it

Comment: I'am getting this warning "Using setJavaScriptEnabled can introduce XSS vulnerabilities into you application, review carefully."

Comment: this is the feature of webview you will have to enable javaScript.

Comment: it says on the device "webpage is unavailable"

Comment: No problem I fixed it, I forgot to add the permission to the manifest

Comment: @Riturajsuman thanks for your answer,passing with separate URL done the Trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try browser to open pdf file in that like below code:

```
http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=yoururl
```

where yoururl will be your pdf url link.